# Pandas Dataframe - Replace NULL value with current_time

Tags: python, pandas, time, na, missing-data

I've a dataframe with a column that gives me a value in type time (e.g. 08:00:00). What I am trying to do is:
in case of my value is None I replace with current time.

For that I am trying with this:

```
current_date = dt.datetime.now()
current_time = current_date.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
df['time'] = df['time'].fillna(current_time).dt.time
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
builtins.AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `current_time` is a string, and you `Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values`

Comment: Use `pd.to_datetime(df['time']).fillna(current_time).dt.time`

Comment: Or `pd.to_timedelta(df['time'].fillna(current_time))`

Comment: I test both solutions but I am getting the same issue: "builtins.AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values". My current code: df['time'] = df['time'].dt.time.fillna(current_time).dt.time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
current_date = dt.datetime.now()
current_time = current_date.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
df['time'] = df['time'].fillna(dt.datetime.strptime(current_time, '%H:%M:%S').time())
```